# How to change the table name in the query with spring hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I had this entity named "User"

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username;

    private String password;
```

but then I had this error message below and find out that "USER" is a reserved keyword in postgresql

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 14

> STATEMENT:  create table user (id int8 not null .....

Then I tried to rename the table using Table annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ACCOUNT")
public class User {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username;

    private String password;
```

But the problem still persists, How do I resolve this? Do I need to change the class name?

EDIT:
additional information, I run all the spring boot and postgres service with docker compose.
I use H2 in the first place and it created the user table with no problem.

Comment: Have you tried the statement directly in postgresql console?

Comment: What is the name of your table in the database ?

Comment: is 'update', not 'create' in line:  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  of config file 'persistence.xml' ?

Comment: @AndrzejWięcławski I use create-drop

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a table called `user` in postgres we defined the entity as follows

`@Table(name = "\"user\"")`

I'm not sure why you weren't able to change the name to USER_ACCOUNT in your example above as the syntax look correct. It would probably be the better solution rather than creating a table called `user`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need delete table user, or you cat rename it to users.

Comment: the db is initialized by hibernate so there are no user table in the first place

Comment: Check spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property into application.properties

Answer (score 0):

My bad

I haven't repackage the app to a new jar file

That's why the docker still building the old jar file

Comment: you can post this answer into your question's comment section.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

keyword  "USER" is reserved in postgresql,
i solved this problem by changing the name in @Table like that :

```
@Table(name="\"User\"")
```